# Is there any way Wait until “Write complete” while write csv in node js

Tags: node.js, csv, asynchronous, npm, fs

I am using "csv-write-stream" npm, but how to make ensure if a file is finished writing.

Below is the code:

```
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream')
var writer = csvWriter()
writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'))
writer.write({hello: "world", foo: "bar", baz: "taco"})
writer.end()
```

I use below code to check if file is complete,but after checking no data found in csv file.

```
writer.on('end', function() {

    process.exit();
});
```

I need to send mail only after if csv complete.

Comment: Have you tried using the [`close`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close_1) event instead of `end`?

Comment: I tried for close event but 'close' event not being triggered.